# Modifying fields InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an Infopath form for adding user contacts to sharepoint. This form has option for end user to select their title with predefined list by ticking the appropriate check box. I have recevied a change request to have new titles added to the list and few of the old ones to remove. I am reluctant to remove the existing title fields since many of the previous data were published and may referencing them. Will there be a data loss if i remove these field from Infopath form? How would i still achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the existing records will not be edited, there will be no data loss. A choice field provides a means of data validation by allowing only defined values, but the actual value is stored as text. If no re-evaluation of that field is triggered, the item will be fine.